# `font-weight` Is not working on chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Just tested something that works perfect on firefox and chrome doesn't makes anyhing with `font-weight: bold/bolder` property.

I tried to look up for another CSS property that may be overwriting it and there is none, also Google has no answers for me..

```
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 50px;
font-size:38px;
font-weight: bolder;
```

Comment: Can you create a working example on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post it here?

Comment: [no-repro](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mfw7e/). Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) since the problem basically must be elsewhere.

Comment: Something else is wrong. It is bold in your example fiddle. In fact, it is bold twice, once based on your `#CountDownPanel` style declaration and once for the `.box` style declaration.

Comment: @Ricardo: Instead of editing your question and adding "*SOLVED*" to the title, please post the solution as an answer to the question and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome not respecting font weight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249654/chrome-not-respecting-font-weight)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved with:

```
font-weight: 900;
font-family: "Arial Black", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. The property must be getting overwritten somewhere or there is a mistake in your html structure somewhere. When you inspect the element via Chrome inspector do you see that it has the bolder style attribute?

http://jsfiddle.net/NNBZB/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@font-face` for the `font-family`, then you are probably experiencing [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31833).

I'm having the same problem, but with Chrome ignoring `font-weight:normal` and using bold by default - it's doesn't even look like the bold version should, and there is no anti-aliasing.

Comment: In my case, I had `font-weight` in the `@font-face` rule which was overriding  my classes' `font-weight` even though they had `!important`.