# Can't style text on input submit button as bold?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style the font in an input button as bold.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="submit" id="nm-match" class="nm-button" value="Match" />
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.nm-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

All the styles are being applied apart from the bold.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CJg43/1/

UPDATE: Why the close votes? Here's a screenshot of how it looks for me, in Chrome on MacOS:

[image]

UPDATE 2: ... and for comparison, here's how it looks with the solution (`background-color: white`) applied - http://jsfiddle.net/CJg43/23/

[image]

Comment: looks fine to me, what browser are you using

Comment: Chrome - sorry, should have specified.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome as well

Comment: works fine in chrome here. chrome's bold isn't the same as FF's though. It's "less bold", but still bolder than normal text.

Comment: AFAIK, the numeric value for 'bold' font-weight is 700, not 600

Comment: How do yo infer that the text is not bold?

Comment: Seems to be an issue in chrome only. See this fiddle in both Chrome and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/CJg43/22/ In chrome, all 2 button have normal text. In firefox, the bold is being respected in 2nd and 3rd button. (P.S. The tests were done on Macbook Pro. `Chrome version 32.0.1700.107` and `Firefox version 26.0`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome not respecting font weight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249654/chrome-not-respecting-font-weight)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using chrome for a MacOS? If so, try adding a background-color to the button to see if it fixes it. The default Aqua styles might be interfering. You can also try `-webkit-appearance: none;` or `-webkit-appearance: button;`.

Comment: i have no idea but that sound most plausible

Comment: What are the default Aqua styles, and how can I turn them off?!

Comment: They are the default styles applied to buttons by chrome on MacOS. Try this in your css: `-webkit-appearance: button;`.

Answer (score 7):

When you use numeric values with the `font-weight` property and you want to use `bold` then use the value greater than or equal to `700`

```
.nm-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CJg43/13/)**

Comment: i just used  font-weight: 600; to make submit button text bold, works fine, thank you.