# Can't format html form elements (label and input) using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble editing a button using CSS. No matter what I do, all I can change is the color of the font (I've only tried color and font-weight). Is there a reason why I can't manipulate the html element using css?

```css
#login-frame {
 color: #900;
}

#login-text {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
   <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
 </label>
</td>
```

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: possible dublicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664610/cant-style-text-on-input-submit-button-as-bold

Comment: Maybe some of css below rewrites your style. Try to add `!important` after property definition: `#login-text { color: red !important; }`

Comment: Do you want to change the font color for button? If yes, then use like this `#login-text input{color:red;}`

Comment: seems okay to me.. was able to change lots of things: http://jsfiddle.net/3gfrxnLt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `appearance: none`, with the relevant vendor prefixes.

```css
#login-frame {
 color: #900;
}

#login-text {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
   <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
 </label>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have given the color code in wrong class as

```
 #login-frame 
 {
    color:/* #900;*/
 }
```

put in this class

```
 #login-text 
 {
     color: #990000;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**what you did wrong :**

you are applying color to parent not to child  you can  use

- ## login-text{color}
- ## login-frame input{color....}
- ## login-frame #login-text{color....}

> **NOTE:** You has to understand how **css** work
>
> - If you have to apply style from parent to child then use parent[space]child
> - If you want to apply style to child directly then use class or id of that element

**Example 1:   #login-text{color}**

```css
#login-text {
 font-weight: bold;
    color: #900;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
   <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
 </label>
</td>
```

**Example 2: #login-frame input{color....}** in example 2 you can also use

> ## login-frame input#login-text

```css
#login-frame input{
 color: #900;
}

#login-text {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
   <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
 </label>
</td>
```

**Example 3:  #login-frame #login-text{color....}**

```css
#login-frame #login-text{
 color: #900;
}

#login-text {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <label id="login-frame" for="login-text">
   <input value="Log In" tabindex="4" id="login-text" type="submit">
 </label>
</td>
```